I can't find service in lan using android nsd
I developing multiplayer game, that uses lan. I using libgdx framework. Now i try to find in local network my game using android Nsd. I can't find service in lan using this method. Please, help me find issue or give me advice, which another metod for making connection i can use? (i choose nsd, because i don't need a lot of permissions and they are normal, next option i see is wifi direct, but it needs more effort)
I can find service on machine what running my code, but I can't find service on another machine with same code runned at same lan, at same ssid. My phones: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 (30 api) and Xiaomi Redmi 9C NFC (29 api)
How i use Nsd
At launcer i create implementations and give them context to get NsdManager.
At screen i give name and port to serverRegistration to use them for server registration
At screen#show() i registrate my service and at render loop after delay(now this delay 0ms) i once start discovering and can't get service not from local machine
When i running code i open HostsScreen on both phones
Important parts of my code
Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:isGame="true"
        android:appCategory="game"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
        <activity
            android:name="com.timetorunclient.game.AndroidLauncher"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


ServerDiscovery implementation
public class ServerDiscoveryImpl implements ServerDiscovery {
    private static final String TAG = "discoveryService";
    private final NsdManager nsdManager;

    public ServerDiscoveryImpl(Context context){
        nsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    NsdManager.DiscoveryListener discoveryListener;
    Context context;
//    WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    boolean started;

    @Override
    public void startDiscovery() {

        discoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String s, int i) {
                Log.e(TAG, "DiscoveryStartFailed");
                nsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String s, int i) {
                Log.e(TAG, "StopDiscoveryFailed");
                nsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDiscoveryStarted(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DiscoveryStarted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDiscoveryStopped(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DiscoveryStopped");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
                System.out.println("omg, i found it");
                NsdManager.ResolveListener resolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int i) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "resolve error");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
                        System.out.println(nsdServiceInfo.getServiceName()
                                + " " + nsdServiceInfo.getServiceType()
                                + " " + nsdServiceInfo.getHost().getHostAddress()
                                + " " + nsdServiceInfo.getPort());
                        ServerInfo info = new ServerInfo(
                                new InetSocketAddress(nsdServiceInfo.getHost(), nsdServiceInfo.getPort()),
                                nsdServiceInfo.getServiceName()
                        );
                        servers.add(info);
                    }
                };
                nsdManager.resolveService(nsdServiceInfo, resolveListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
                servers.remove(new ServerInfo(
                        new InetSocketAddress(nsdServiceInfo.getHost(), nsdServiceInfo.getPort()),
                        nsdServiceInfo.getServiceName()
                ));
            }
        };
//        lock = ((WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createMulticastLock(TAG);
//        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
//        lock.acquire();
        nsdManager.discoverServices("_myApp._udp", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener);
        started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void endDiscovery() {
        if(!started){
            return;
        }
        started = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "endDiscovery");
        nsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(discoveryListener);
//        lock.release();
    }
}

ServerRegistration implementation
public class ServerRegistrationImpl implements ServerRegistration {
    final private String TAG = "TTR Service registration";

    final NsdManager manager;
    InetSocketAddress address = null;
    String name = null;
    boolean started = false;
    NsdManager.RegistrationListener registrationListener;
    String actualName;
//    WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    Context context;

    public ServerRegistrationImpl(Context context){
        manager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void register() {
        if(address == null || name == null){
            return;
        }
        registrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int i) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Service failed registration");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int i) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Service failed registration");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
                actualName = nsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
                Log.d(TAG, "Service registered with name: " + actualName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service unregistered");
            }
        };

        NsdServiceInfo info = new NsdServiceInfo();
        info.setServiceName(name);
        info.setServiceType("_myApp._udp");
        info.setPort(address.getPort());

//        lock = ((WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createMulticastLock(TAG);
//        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
//        lock.acquire();

        manager.registerService(info, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, registrationListener);

        started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister() {
        if(!started){
            return;
        }
        started = false;
        manager.unregisterService(registrationListener);
//        lock.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAddress(InetSocketAddress address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        if(Objects.equals(name, "")){
            return;
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
}

AndroidLauncher
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    private static final String TAG = "launcher";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        ServerDiscovery discovery = new ServerDiscoveryImpl(this);
        ServerRegistration registration = new ServerRegistrationImpl(this);

        initialize(new TimeToRun(discovery, registration), config);
    }
}


HostScreen, screen which i open on both phones to see results
public class HostScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    TimeToRun game; // thing, that keeps implementations after making new instance and doesn't do with them anything
    <omitted>
    long time;

    public HostScreen(TimeToRun game){
        this.game = game;
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
        <omitted>
        time = TimeUtils.millis();

        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            game.setScreenAndLoadNeededResources(TimeToRun.AppScreens.MENU);
            return;
        }

        game.registration.setName(Gdx.app.getPreferences("social").getString("name"));
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(socket.getLocalAddress(), socket.getLocalPort());
        game.registration.setAddress(address);
        game.registration.register();


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    <omitted>    
    if(TimeUtils.millis() >= time && time != -1){
            game.discovery.startDiscovery();
            time = -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        <omitted>
        game.registration.unregister();
        game.discovery.endDiscovery();
    }
}


I search some solutions on Stack Overflow and both delay before start disovery and wifi multicast lock didn't help me.
Log cat (no matter what i do, on both devices)
2024-08-03 21:44:13.688 20269-20299 discoveryService        com.timetorunclient.game             D  DiscoveryStarted
2024-08-03 21:44:14.329 20269-20299 TTR Servic...gistration com.timetorunclient.game             D  Service registered with name: anon659892
2024-08-03 21:44:14.579 20269-20299 System.out              com.timetorunclient.game             I  omg, i found it
2024-08-03 21:44:14.594 20269-20299 System.out              com.timetorunclient.game             I  anon659892 ._myApp._udp 192.168.0.181 38704


